# Turn on/off local notification with switch in different controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

For my simple alarm clock app in ViewController1 I have an ON button, OFF button and SET button.

When I click the SET button it takes you to a popover (ViewController 2) with a date picker where you can pick the date and set the alarm (a local notification). When I do this the alarm goes off as intended.

What i would like to do is set the alarm, and when I press the OFF button the alarm does not go off. But when i press the ON button the alarm will go off with the previous time.

Could someone point me in the right direction for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own management for your notifications. This management part has to know which notification is active (and is registered as real local notification) and which should be in future.
If you have done this, you could do what ever you want.

Comment: Ok Great! But how do i do this?

Comment: Use a class (e.g. MyNotification) that holds all information about one of your notifications. If you add a new MyNotification by your app, add this new one to a list (e.g. MyNewNotifications).
When no more notification will be added and you will transfer this list to real localnotification system: transfer it and save your MyNewNotifications list in a file. This file holds the situation which notification is active. 
If you want to add a new MyNotification to your MyNewNotifications list, do it. But dont transfer it without testing against the list saved in your file, and save the new again.